# How can I change my Lenovo Legion Y520 keyboard light from white to red?

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop

The pictures I see have red lights but mine has white lights. Can I change it or is it part of the model?

my model can only have white light.

Comment: Did you buy the laptop new or used?

Comment: bought it like last week in Octagon.

Comment: Does your lid look like [Option A](https://www.lenovo.com/medias/ideapad-y520-gallery06.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wxMTA3NDF8aW1hZ2UvanBlZ3xpbWFnZXMvaGM4L2g2OC85MzU5NzAwNjg4OTI2LmpwZ3w4MzEyNzg5OWQxYWM1ZTBjNmMyZWExZmYwNWQyYzc4ZDg4OTZiOGRlNjU4NTVkNTI4MWIyNGNiY2NkZDY1N2U5) or [Option B](https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/5/7/10175275/l_10175275_001.jpg)

Comment: option b is how it looks like

Comment: Then you have a Lenovo Legion Y520 limited "black and gold" edition, which has a white backlit keyboard instead of red.

Comment: is mine better or the option a model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82943/discussion-between-furiousblaze3000-and-drzoo).